# Ajax Control Toolkit Calendar doesn't show in IE8 when inside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

I'm having this problem. When the calendar extender is outside an UpdatePanel, it works perfectly on IE8, however, when inside it, it doesn't show. Anybody having this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: @JP Araujo ~ Did you ever find the solution to the problem on this one?

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember that now. My bad. But I eliminated some update panels to solve some problems on the project I was working on, so, maybe I hadn't find a solution.

Comment: lol, I know the feeling. Alrighty then. Maybe it will come to you. I'm just having some odd IE8/UpdatePanel issues of my own, thought I would check.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound crazy, but I had the same issue, and fixed it by removing the TabIndex from the image (that opens the calendar). IE8 doesn't like it when you have a TabIndex on the image.

My calendar opens up inside the update panel ok now :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: tabindex is all lowercase in the specs and in the HTML.